# How do I correctly reference gpu-browser.js?

Tags: javascript, gpu, node-modules, gpu.js

This might sound like a stupid question but anyways; When I try to reference the gpu-browser.js file in my html it doesn't affect my other scripts. Its as if I never put it in, when I try to do the code snippet provided in the documentation it gives me this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: GPU is not a constructor`

Specifically my code looks like this:

```html
    <script src="node_modules/gpu.js/dist/gpu-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // GPU is a constructor and namespace for browser
        const gpu = new GPU();
        const multiplyMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(a, b) {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
                sum += a[this.thread.y][i] * b[i][this.thread.x];
            }
            return sum;
        }).setOutput([512, 512]);
    
        const c = multiplyMatrix(a, b);
    </script>
```

I installed gpu.js with npm --save and am using Python version 3.11.